# how to specify the pom.xml path in jenkins pipeline script

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

my maven project looks like below
[working dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmBy5.png)
[Jenkins error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18PQB.png)

this is how my script looks like

```
node {
    stage ('Build') {
        git url: 'https://github.com/rakshitha2/test_proj.git'

        def mvnHome = tool 'M3'

        bat "${mvnHome}\\bin\\mvn -B install"
    }
}
```

I have to go inside parent directory and execute maven command in Jenkins pipeline script.
I tried specifying POM path in MVN command its giving me an error saying "path is unexpected at this time". but the same is working in my local.

I'm new to Jenkins and groovy. kindly help me with this.

Comment: add you pom.xml to question and the log of the error so people can understand the issue

Comment: Hi, issue is not with the pom, I need to go inside parent directory where pom is located and execute the MVN command. but still I'm adding my error screen shot

Answer (score 12):

As it is basically a normal maven mechanism. So

```
 sh 'mvn -f otherdirectory/pom.xml clean install'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'mavenHome'
        jdk 'JavaHome'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'maven clean'
                //ABC indicates the folder name where the pom.xml file resides
                bat ' mvn -f ABC/pom.xml clean install'  
            }
            post {
                success {
                    echo 'Now Archiving'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to enter into the directory and execute the command in this way:

```
sh '''
          cd otherdirectory
          mvn clean install
    '''
```